# How to get info from chrome.tabs.onCreate before chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest fires?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm using both chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest and chrome.tabs.onCreate listeners in my extension. I'm trying to utilize the tab.openerTabId attribute that you get in tabs.onCreate, to have it available by the time the webRequest.onBeforeRequest callback runs, but onBeforeRequest seems to be running before tabs.onCreate fires. Is there any simple way around this?

```
var openerTabId;

function checkNewTab(tab) {
    openerTabId = tab.openerTabId;
}

function checkRedirects(details) {
    //code that I don't want to run until I have openerTabId in those 
    //instances where web request is due to a new tab being opened
}

function setupNewTabListener() {
    chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(checkNewTab);
}

function setUpRedirectListener() {
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(checkRedirects);
    var filter = createFilter(redirects);
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(checkRedirects, filter, ["blocking"]);
}

function setupInitial() {
    '''
    setupNewTabListener();
    setUpRedirectListener();
    '''
}

chrome.storage.local.get({
    '''
    setupInitial();
});
```

Comment: You can try to disable [prefetching in browser settings](https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-prefetch). AFAIK there are no other solutions as the observed behavior is a consequence of the multi-threaded browser architecture where the tabs UI and network stack are working independently.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix/alternative for this? I'm having a similar issue. I log all tabs myself, to get around the problem of tabs.query being a callback. So I can get the proper tab information/details inside webRequest.onBeforeRequest. I'm suffering the same problem that sometimes the tabs.onCreated is executed after onBeforeRequest and the tab details are not available.